# I cannot import a photo with directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pygame, photo

My code is getting this error whenever I type it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Passion Project Files\Passion-Project.py", line 16, in <module>
    self.image = pygame.image.load("C:Users\chris\Desktop\Passion Project Files\Resources\bg.jpg").convert()
pygame.error: Couldn't open C:Users\chris\Desktop\Passion Project Files\Resources\bg.jpg
```

and here is my code:

```
   import random
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

pygame.display.set_caption("PP Example")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "Images")
background_image = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg").convert()

while not done:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
      done = True
  screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

  pygame.display.flip()

  clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Updated Code Still Not Working

I have seen other people have used the same method but I don't know if I changed something and don't see it or if it just doesn't work anymore because most of the ones I have found seem to be very old for when they were posted and solved but I don't think they were so old that the solution has changed

Comment: Do you need `C:\Users` instead of `C:Users`?  It's hard to spot typo's like these, because you kind-of read what your brain tells you is there, not what is actually written.

Answer (score 1):

Please use an [r-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for backwhacks.

You won't be happy with the results of `"chris\new project\test\bg.jpg"`,
as the newline and TAB will offer an unpleasant surprise.

```
r"C:Users\chris\Desktop\Passion Project Files\Resources\bg.jpg"
```

Also, unless `os.getcwd()` reports you're at the root directory,
you should start with an initial slash:

```
r"C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Passion Project Files\Resources\bg.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why it's not working but try this.

Put the image in a folder inside your project folder.

Have os library do the work for you. It will make sure that file path will be accessed by most computers.

```
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "theNameOfYourImageFolder")
```

Then you have to define and instantiate whatever it is you are using self on. Like if it's for a sprite for example...

```
class Whatever(pygame.sprite.Sprite)
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_folder,"justTheFileName.jpg"))
.convert()
```

The above should happen before pygame.init(). Than after init somewhere.

```
Whatever = Whatever()
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This  seemed like it would work and I adjusted it to where it was the name of my image folder though I still get the same problem.

Comment: Not certain if this is part of it but isn't it ` screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))`. I don't think that'll fix it and I'm not certain if that matters